# iOS HealthKit Project using HKActivitySummaryQuery - Summaries Always Nil

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

Objective: Read from HealthKit My Activity Data ( i.e. activity ring data - move calories, workout minutes, and stands )

Problem Experienced: Result Handler returns 'nil' HKActivitySummary Array

What I have Attempted:

I have added the HealthKit Capability to the project and added the two info.plist requirements:

> Privacy - Health Share Usage Description

> Privacy - Health Update Usage Description

And ensured I tapped "allow all" for permissions when the permission request popup appears for HealthKit within the iPhone.

I also have many weeks of activity data recorded so that should also be fine.

How can I retrieve the array of HKActivitySummary objects in order to replicate the rings within my iOS app.

My Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad() 
  startQueryForActivitySummary(view: self.view)
}

func startQueryForActivitySummary(view: UIView) {
  
  let calendar = NSCalendar.current
  let endDate = Date()
  
  guard let startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: endDate) else {
    fatalError("*** Unable to create the start date ***")
  }
  
  let units: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.day, .month, .year, .era]
  var startDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents(units, from: startDate)
  startDateComponents.calendar = calendar
  var endDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents(units, from: endDate)
  endDateComponents.calendar = calendar
  
  let queryPredicate = HKQuery.predicate(forActivitySummariesBetweenStart: startDateComponents,
                                         end: endDateComponents)
  let query = HKActivitySummaryQuery(predicate: queryPredicate) { (query, summaries, error) -> Void in
    if let summaries = summaries { // print(summaries) before this line will always return nil.
      if let summary = summaries.first {
        let activeEnergyBurned = summary.activeEnergyBurned.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.kilocalorie())
        let activeEnergyBurnedGoal = summary.activeEnergyBurnedGoal.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.kilocalorie())
        let activeEnergyBurnGoalPercent = round(activeEnergyBurned/activeEnergyBurnedGoal)
        
        let frame    = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
        let ringView = HKActivityRingView(frame: frame)
        view.addSubview(ringView)
        ringView.setActivitySummary(summary, animated: true)
      }
    }
  }
  
  let allTypes = Set([HKObjectType.workoutType(),
                      HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .activeEnergyBurned)!])
  
  let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
  healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: allTypes, read: allTypes) { (success, error) in 
    healthStore.execute(query)
  }
}
```

Comment: I copied your code and the auth did not seem to call. I got nil like you. I moved the auth outside of this code and when the auth ran, I no longer get nil. But I still get 0 summaries and like you, I have data that should return. Sorry, not too helpful.

Comment: @johnelemans it helps a bit thanks for the attempt! I wonder if it has to do with what data i must request authorization for then. Im not sure if Im just supposed to have an array requesting every data healthpoint a user has. seems odd but clarification from anyone would help! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing permission HKObjectType.activitySummaryType()

Extend you types like this:

```
    let allTypes = Set([
            HKObjectType.workoutType(),
            HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .activeEnergyBurned)!,
            HKObjectType.activitySummaryType()
        ])
```

Here is the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkobjecttype/1615319-activitysummarytype